Prove that the sequence of points given by the gradient descent algorithm converges to zero.
This is an exercise and it seemed pretty simpl at a first glance but I don't how to continue. I have this function:
If $x < 0 $ then $f(x) = \frac{3}{2}x^{2}$
If $x \geq 0 $ then $f(x) = x^{4}$
Then I have to proove that the sequence of points $u_{n}$ given by the gradient descent algorithm converges to zero. The step size is $\eta = \frac{1}{2}$ and the initial point is $u_{0}= 1$
The algorithm says that
$$ u_{n+1} = u_{n} - \frac{1}{2} f'(u_{n}) $$
Simplifying some calculations that I have done:
If $u_{n} <0 $
$$ u_{n+1} = -\frac{u_{n}}{2}$$
If $u_{n} \geq 0 $
$$ u_{n+1} = u_{n} - 2 u^{3}_{n} $$
I checked that the last term $u_{n} < 0 $ is $u_{1} = -1$.
I was tempted to use the Banach fixed-point theorem but I couldn't proove that the equation used by the algorithm $g(x) = x - \eta f'(x)$ is a Contraction mapping.
Also, I tried to use a result about attractor points ( $|g'(0)| < 1 $) but it is not working because the function $g''(x) $ is not continous in zero.
Could you give me some advice or hints? Thanks in advance.

$u_2=1/2.$ Use induction to show that the ratio $u_{n+1}/u_n < 1/2$, and conclude with the ratio test (comparison to a geometric series).

You have shown that $u_n \ge 0$ for $n \ge 2$.
We can take advantage of that observation.
For $n\ge 2$, we have
$$u_{n+1}-u_n=-2u_n^3 \le 0$$
That is the sequence is decreasing.
Hence, by monotone convergence theorem, the sequence converges.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} u_{n+1}= \lim_{n \to \infty} (u_n - 2u_n^3)$$
leads to the conclusion that $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n = 0$.
